# Object changes even though console.log is before the line that would make the change

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

When I run the piece of JS below, the console outputs object 1 with the key "course" being "JS4", instead of JS2, which it was originally, even though console.log is written before the line where the change would occur. I would expect the changes only to be logged in the console if I would've written another `console.log(courses)` after `courses[1].course="JS4";`

```
const courses = [
  { teacher: "X", course: "JS" },
  { teacher: "X2", course: "JS2" }
];

courses.push({ teacher: "X3", course: "JS3" });
console.log(courses);

courses[1].course = "JS4";
```

Comment: cant reproduce your error, check my snippet in the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code. You are probably checking inside the Google Chrome console, which always shows the updated value of any variable.

So if there is a change after a `console.log` statement, you will see the updated value.

Answer (score 0):

There nothing wrong with the code, its browsers behavior. To see the response even in developer console (Chrome), you can make use JSON.stringify:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(c)))
```

I think the below snippet will resolve your issue:

```
const courses = [
  { teacher: "X", course: "JS" },
  { teacher: "X2", course: "JS2" }
];

courses.push({ teacher: "X3", course: "JS3" });
console.log(JSON.stringify(courses)); // [{"teacher":"X","course":"JS"},{"teacher":"X2","course":"JS2"},{"teacher":"X3","course":"JS3"}]

courses[1].course = "JS4";
console.log(JSON.stringify(courses)); // [{"teacher":"X","course":"JS"},{"teacher":"X2","course":"JS4"},{"teacher":"X3","course":"JS3"}]
```

Please find the screen shot of the code executed in developer tool:

[Code in developer tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDpuV.png)